# The term 'pyenv' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, windows-10, pyenv

I am on windows10:
PS C:\Users\hp\Documents\Projects> `pip install pip --target $HOME\\.pyenv`

pyenv got installed successfully.

PS C:\Users\hp\Documents\Projects> `pyenv`

```
The term 'pyenv' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to you `PATH` variable

```
%USERPROFILE%\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin
%USERPROFILE%\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims
```

Comment: Instructions for those who are unsure about how to add PATH, search in Windows for Advanced system settings. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, add a new PATH environment variable.